# Why does instanceof check return false when tsconfig target is set to es5 vs true when set to esnext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I moved a working React component to its own repo/package in order to improve code maintainability.

When using the following `tsconfig.json`, `instanceof` check returns `false` when it should return `true`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This is my first time moving a working React component to its own repo/package. Is it normal to use `"target": "esnext"`? I initially chose `es5` based on what `create-react-app` uses.

The project is written in TypeScript (`.tsx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by a TypeScript [edge case](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work).

`Object.setPrototypeOf(this, FooError.prototype);` solved my issue.

Example:

```js
class FooError extends Error {
  constructor(m: string) {
    super(m);

    // Set the prototype explicitly.
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, FooError.prototype);
  }

  sayHello() {
    return "hello " + this.message;
  }
}
```